# Targeting iOS 4.x devices under XCode 4.6

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, xcode4.6

I'have Xcode 4.6 and the minimum iOS version I can target is 4.3 !
How can I target iOS 4.x devices using my XCode ? Is that possible ?

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xcode 4.6 (and 4.5) can not target lower than 4.3. You can download older versions of Xcode than can target lower versions of iOS from Apple:
https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=Xcode

You can use several versions of Xcode in parallel.

Comment: Note though, that you can't use iOS 6 features while still supporting  iOS versions lower than 4.3, as the iOS 6 SDK isn't available for older Xcode versions.

Comment: Also you can't support ARMv6 devices and run full-screen on an iPhone 5. You can engineer a build that would work with a suitably old Xcode and by supplying a Default-568h but Apple won't allow such a binary to be submitted — it'll be rejected immediately by the automatic validation tool.

Comment: Thank you All of you ! But how about the submission into app store ! should I do multiple build for older version ? The probleme is : I have to target my application from iOS 4 to the latest version ! is older version of XCode can do that for me ?

Comment: You say you "have to" target iOS 4... what is driving this requirement?  Unless you're working on something particularly unusual, it's probably a mistake to roll back to earlier versions of Xcode to support such an old version of iOS.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree with @Jim - Apple doesn't support less than iOS 4.3 in Xcode... is there a more clear sign to move on with the times?

Comment: I agree with you ! but My boss have to be convinced about that too ! The fact is : I'am building a custom solution for one of our client and I have to target some old devices ! But JRG-Developer's argument seems to be great ! Thank you gays !

Comment: For new apps I am only supporting 5.0 an up, for old ones 4.3 (but nothing less). I have dialog telling user whats new in a version. When I am about to move up I am adding a statement like "This is the last version that will support x.x". I have yet to receive any complaints.

Comment: I might chime in that just because Apple says so does not make it right. Of course they want developers to require new hardware so they can sell more hardware. Hundreds of thousands of apps existed before iOS 4... and performed fine. Why cut them off? It should be a developers decision based on anticipated needs.

Comment: But I can only see iOS 5 simulator. Where to get the iOS 4.3 simulator in Xcode 4.6?

Comment: Where you set the scheme (pick simulator or device) you have a choice of "more simulators" where you can download the 4.3 simulator.